# Google Cast SDK 2.3.0 for iOS doesn't support 64-bit

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

It seems like the [2.3.0 version of the Google Cast SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastFramework-2.3.0-Release.zip) stopped supporting the `arm64` architecture (it does support `x86_64` though, making it work in the 64-bit simulator)

```
 λ: cd GoogleCast.framework     
 λ: file GoogleCast     
 GoogleCast: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
 GoogleCast (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):   current ar archive
 GoogleCast (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
 GoogleCast (for architecture armv7s):  current ar archive random library
 GoogleCast (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
 GoogleCast (for architecture x86_64):  current ar archive random library
```

Therefore, I get this error when building for a physical device:

```
ld: archive has no table of contents file '/Users/****/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast' for architecture arm64
```

Comment: We are looking into this. It will be tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=332&start=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=324&can=1&q=arm64

adding -all_load in Other Linker Flag made it work with arm64 but I still get warnings about a missing dwarf:

"warning: (arm64) /Users/marksp/Documents/src/tvmp-iview-ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastFramework-2.3.0-Release/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast(CastProtos.o) object file doesn't contain DWARF debug information"

Comment: not working for me. This lead to a lot of duplicate symbols on link.

Answer (score 2):

If you install 2.3.0.1 via CocoaPods, insert the code below in Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  `ranlib Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastFramework-2.3.0-Release/GoogleCast.framework/Versions/A/GoogleCast`
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If **-all_load** flag doesn't work for you (because of 3rd party libraries)

You can use `ranlib` like this :

`ranlib GoogleCast.framework/Versions/A/GoogleCast`

[Source : google cast mailing list](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=324)