# Google Cast SDK 2.5.0 missing required architecture arm64

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast, iphone-6, iphone-64bit

I'm trying to build an iOS app using Google Cast SDK 2.5.0 and am able to build on an iPhone 5 device, but when I try to build on an iPhone 6 device, I get the following build error:

ld: warning: ignoring file ./GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast, missing required architecture arm64 in file ./GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast (3 slices)

I noticed a post about a similar issue here:
[Google Cast SDK 2.3.0 for iOS doesn't support 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798718/google-cast-sdk-2-3-0-for-ios-doesnt-support-64-bit)

And so I tried this:
ranlib GoogleCast.framework/Versions/A/GoogleCast

But I'm still missing arm 64. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: download again at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads. I run lipo -info to show supported architect. lipo -info Versions/A/GoogleCast 
Architectures in the fat file: Versions/A/GoogleCast are: arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I had two versions of the framework and Xcode was not using the one I thought it was. Running lipo -info revealed it was the wrong one.

Comment: any update on this, I'm getting an error while running the app on simulator 
Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-ios-4.7.0_static/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast(GCKCastContext+UI.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '~/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-ios-4.7.0_static/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast' for architecture arm64 (M1)

Answer (score 0):

As charmingToad mentioned in the comments, I had two versions of the Cast SDK being linked in my application.  Removing the older version fixed the linking errors.

If you are using Cocoapods, all you need is a `pod update` to update your version of the Cast SDK.

If after upgrade Xcode is complaining about linker issues, adding `-all_load` as a compiler flag worked for me.